# How to charge a credit card that was already used on file via iATS

Tags: civicontribute

A donor requested I charge their card for a donation with their card that is already on file. It's not a recurring contribution. I tried to view their card number from their previous donations, but it won't let me because it's tied to the payment processor. Do I need to ask them for their card number again?

Answer (score 1):

yes you need to ask them again. For obvious security reason, you're not supposed to see the credit card number. The payment gateway (IATS, Stripe...) will itself not record the full credit card number. You would actually only see the last 4 digits if you would have access to it.